# Получение результата математического выражения из строки

Tags: delphi, vcl

Есть ли возможность реализовать следующую концепцию?
В поле `TextEdit` задается математическое выражение, например `2*2+2`. При нажатии на кнопку (или любое другое событие), поле калькулируется и получается результат `6`, которое вставляется в это же поле `TextEdit`.

Другими словами, существуют ли в Delphi методы, которые из строки вида математического выражения возвращают результат из этого выражения?

Comment: в штатной поставке - нет. Но есть, например, JCL с TEvaluator

Comment: @kami я выяснил некоторые моменты и провёл собственное расследование, придя к тому, что данное возможно из коробки (штатной поставке).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем, я нашёл где-то в закулисьях интернета один примечательный, но наверняка не совсем безопасный метод реализации данного компонента из коробки в `VCL`. Опишу его реализацию и работу.

Создадим VCL форму из двух компонентов, `TEdit` как `edt1` и `TButton` как `btn1`, чисто для теста на событие.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Внутри кода нужно дополнить секцию `uses` следующими модулями:

```
uses
...
System.Bindings.EvalProtocol,
System.Bindings.Evaluator,
System.Bindings.EvalSys,
System.Rtti
...
```

Из документации выяснил, что `System.Bindings.EvalProtocol` содержит интерфейсы  для различных аспектов привязки данных, в том числе и скомпилированные выражения, а `System.Bindings.Evaluator` имеет в себе метод `Compile`, который может компилировать выражения с помощью оболочки `IScope`, возвращая `ICompiledBinding`, его же можно использовать для вычисления результата компиляции.

`System.Bindings.EvalSys` содержит в себе базовые операторы для работы с `LiveBindings`. `System.Rtti` в свою очередь содержит в себе классы, которые могут манипулировать классами объектов, что обеспечит более глубокую привязку во время выполнения кода.

Зная это, можно реализовать следующий код в событии на нажатие кнопки `btn1`:

```
procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  expr:string;
  Result: Extended;
  LScope: IScope;
  LCompiledExpr: ICompiledBinding;
  LResult: TValue;
begin
  LScope:=BasicOperators;
  LCompiledExpr:=Compile(edt1.Text,LScope);
  LResult:=LCompiledExpr.Evaluate(LScope, nil, nil).GetValue;
  if not LResult.IsEmpty then
  begin
    edt1.Text:=LResult.ToString
  end;
end;
```

Здесь мы собственно производим компиляцию нашего выражения из строки, а далее получаем результат данной компиляции и выводим её как строку, если та не пуста.

Результат выглядит следующим образом:

- Вводим выражение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Нажимаем на кнопку и получаем результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

UPD1

Изучв внутренности компонентов, пришёл к тому, что выражение может состоять только из сложения, вычитания, умножения, деления, отрицания, а так же из логических операторов сравнения, что в общем то делает дела безопаснее. `System.Bindings.Evaluator` имеет в себе следующие референсы:

```
...
// <summary>Enumeration for built-in operators. It is used internally by
  // the expression compiler.</summary>
  TBuiltinOp = (boAdd, boSubtract, boMultiply, boDivide, boNegate,
    boEqualTo, boNotEqual, boLessThan, 
    boLessEqual, boGreaterThan, boGreaterEqual);
...
```